# Own Google assistant: Dialogflow analog to action sdks action.json

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm about to build my first own Google Assistant.
Now with action sdk and the action.json file I managed to extent the assistant. For example I can say: "What's my favorite color?" And the assistant responds: "Blue".
Now I have tried to do the same with DialogFlow instead of the action.json file. But as I see it, I can only build apps here. So I have to start the conversation with: "Start my test app" -> Answers with Main intent -> "Whats my favourite color?" -> "Blue". Or "Ask my test app what my favorite color is". Can I replicate the behaviour of action.json with DialogFlow? So directly ask the assistant: "What's my favorite color" without starting an app first? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm really confused by this, as you never could activate the app directly by saying "What's my favorite color"

Comment: Yeah, it looks like the method with action,json extends the functionality without the need of an app. What I'm using is basically the pushtotalk.py file.

Comment: You're trying to mix Google Assistant SDK with Dialogflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. You need to start the app before hand. If you want to do so, you have to integrate it directly to your google home so in that case the best way to do that using action sdk.
However, this might change from time to time. I last developed for google home like 6 months back, if I am not wrong then back then this was not possible, but I am not quite sure what's the scenario now. I did a little digging but on just an overview of the results, the things are still the same. Even if you find a way of achieving it through dialogflow, then post your answer here, but I don't think that possible.